# Why can't I add a visualforce to a standard edit page?

Tags: visualforce

I know that I can't add a vf section to a std, edit page, but my question is ***WHY***

can't I add visualforce to a standard edit page? What's the exact issue going on there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it's not possible. They are added only in the view page, but there's already an Idea 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS

EDIT:

I guess there a couple of technical issues like for example:

- Visualforce pages are served from a different domain, so that would make saving very complex and risky for data integrity.
- Visualforce pages may contain fields which don't really exist such as fields from wrapper classes.

There are probably some more... I guess if Salesforce managed to offer such a functionality it would have been very limited thus making it not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

As @ManSpan noted, those pages are protected and can't be edited. That said, there's a freebie utility called Layout Page that will allow you to convert standard pages to VisualForce. Once they're in that form, you can then add all of the custom VisualForce you'd like.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason WHY though. I imagine it's not arbitrary..

Comment: I used the term "protected" for a reason. Its so no one can come in and change the default behavior of a standard page without being aware that's what they're doing. Recognize also that not all versions of SF support customizations, including custom controllers or Apex code.